# Visualizing map from Spatialite DB on Mobile

Tags: spatial-database, spatialite, android, mobile, offline

I am working on an Android application for a school project.

I am converting shapefiles ([examples](http://www.fws.gov/southwest/es/AustinTexas/Maps_Data.html)) into SQLite databases using [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) and performing queries on those databases on the mobile with [SpatiaLite-Android](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android).

I am still looking for a way to visually display the map data on Android for user interaction. For example, I would like the user be able to zoom in/out and pan the map around. I also intend show the user her current location with respect to the map.

It would be great if my app can draw maps directly from the SQLite database with SpatiaLite. Can anyone offer tips on this? If this is not possible or not advisable, can anyone suggest alternatives?

NOTE: My app needs to function in offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a local db create from a .shp using tile format stored in db called .mbtiles and for spatial querys still use spatialite. You can use ESRI sdk for android for maps visibility.

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but maybe you could expand on it a bit?

Comment: if you need make spatial querys  you can  convert  a single shp file in sqlite spatialite using spatialite-gui    using a query like  sp_touch   yes like postgis

Comment: url is https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/LocalMBTiles

Comment: using a free tool tilemill you can offline map (tiles stored in sqlite files ) based a shp file and create custom render style yes like a mapfile and using that file you can upload to emulator o download into devices android into de sdcard now you can read this file from map sdk like example esri sdk

Comment: can you edit you answer and add your comments